# Headless install of Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength?

Tags: security, java

Is there a way to install Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength jars without having to download them manually and accept the terms and conditions? I would like to set this up on my servers such that they are able to install these files at startup time.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would likely be to write up a bash or perl /python  script that does that in the background: (something like this)

> /usr/bin/bash
>
> /usr/bin/dialog --yesno "Agree = 'OK'   Disagree = 'Cancel'  Agree = 'OK'   Disagree = 'Cancel'"
>
> if ( test 1 -eq $? ); then
>
> ```
>       sleep 10
>
>    exit 1
> ```
>
> fi
>
> exit 0
>
> fi